# Dynamically add properties to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

In Javascript I created an object like this:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig= {
    'propertyA': 1,
    'PropertyB': 2,
    'PropertyC': 3
};
```

I'm trying to add a new property in runtime but get "Cannot set properties of undefined" error.

Code used example:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD['flag'] = true;
```

What's the proper way to set a new property like this?

Also tried like this:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD.flag = true;
```

Comment: You need to create the `this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD` property first, **then** create the `flag` property on it. You can combine those by assigning an object to it: `this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD = {flag: true};`

Comment: It's unclear what the TypeScript part of this question is...?

Comment: It looks like standard JavaScript with the way `this` isn't in a class, and isn't explicitly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no `propertyD` in the original object, so `accessibilityConfig.propertyD` is `undefined`.

You can dynamically add properties to an object, but that object has to exist first.  This is true for every level of an object's hierarchy.  So before you can do this:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD.flag = true;
```

You'd have to do this:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD = {};
```

Or you can do both at the same time:

```
this.view.objectExample.accessibilityConfig.propertyD = { flag: true };
```